# Google Earth plugin not displaying placemark description from kml

Tags: kml, google-earth-plugin

I seemed to have developed an issue with placemark descriptions not displaying when clicked.  The balloon opens, and by the size it looks like the text might actually be there but it's not displaying.  The page is fairly dynamic, with multiple kml's loading, so I wonder if somewhere I killed the placemarks in the code?  They display fine in the earth app, so I'm assuming it's something with the plugin or the way I'm loading the kml.

Here's an example: http://tour.frederickwildman.com/jaboulet  Any help or advice on how to proceed would be very helpful.  Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your problem is.  I see InfoWindows on the example with text in them.

Comment: Damn, I should have checked other browsers; It looks like this must be an issue in Chrome. Everything is displaying fine in FF and IE.

Comment: I looked at it in Chrome on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to be sure as I can only intermittently reproduce the problem but I think there are two possible issues.

Firstly, you balloons are having their [content scrubbed](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/balloons#scrubbing) be the earth api. You can confirm this by looking at the mark-up of an open balloon. You will see something like the following where content has been removed.

```
<!--
Content-type: mhtml-die-die-die

-->
```

Secondly, the balloons appear to be having an issue resizing due to the content.

To overcome these issues you can choose to handle the balloon events yourself. You can then call [getBalloonHtmlUnsafe()](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/balloons#getballoonhtmlunsafe) for the balloon content scrubbing and 
[setMaxWidth()](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_abstract_balloon.html#abf592cf6d7255495af5d1e7df911ad15) and [setMaxHeight()](https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/reference/interface_g_e_abstract_balloon#afca98d17030f993f1428a96a98fd3b54) for the resizing. e.g.

```
google.earth.addEventListener(ge.getGlobe(), 'click', function(event) {
  // exit if not a placemark
  if(event.getTarget().getType() != 'kmlPlacemark') return; 

  // cancel the default behaviour 
  event.preventDefault(); 

  // get the un-scrubbed content and show the max-sized balloon
  var content = placemark.getBalloonHtmlUnsafe(),
      balloon = ge.createHtmlStringBalloon('');
  balloon.setFeature(event.getTarget());
  balloon.setContentString(content);
  balloon.setMaxWidth(800);
  balloon.setMaxHeight(600);
  ge.setBalloon(balloon);
});
```